# python searching a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, search, increment

I just wanted to ask how you would search a list of tuples in python, say:

```
[("A","B",3),("C","D",4),("E","F",5)]
```

Let's say that the user searches for `"A", "B"`: since `"A", "B"` is in the list, it will increment `3.` and will output the list again

```
[("A","B",4),("C","D",4),("E","F",5)]
```

If the user searches for `"A", "S"`, the program will create a new record and saving it in the database

```
[("A","S",1),("A","B",3),("C","D",4),("E","F",5)]
```

Comment: sounds like you should be using a dictionary, `collections` has `defaultdict` and `Counter` may be useful. @M.Gibson are you allowed to use any libraries such as `collections`?

Comment: Would you ever search on the 2nd element in the tuple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This task would be made simple if you used `collections.Counter`

First you need to create a `Counter` by iterating through the sequence and using a tuple of the first two items eg. `("A", "B")` as the key and the number eg. `3` as the value.

Then you can simply do `c[("A", "B")] += 1` for example. It will also work if the key is not already in the counter eg. `c[("A", "S")] += 1`.

You could create a list from this to output it using a list comprehension but I will leave that to you since this is homework.

Answer (score 0):

```
lis=[["A","B",3],["C","D",4],["E","F",5]]

def search_and_increment(local_list,search):
    for x in local_list:
        if search in ",".join(x[:-1]):
            x[-1]+=1
            return
    else:
        local_list.append(search.split(",")+[1])
        return
```

**output:**

```
>>> search_and_increment(lis,"A,B")
>>> lis
[['A', 'B', 4], ['C', 'D', 4], ['E', 'F', 5]]
>>> search_and_increment(lis,"A,S")
>>> lis
[['A', 'B', 4], ['C', 'D', 4], ['E', 'F', 5], ['A', 'S', 1]]
>>> search_and_increment(lis,"A,S")
>>> lis
[['A', 'B', 4], ['C', 'D', 4], ['E', 'F', 5], ['A', 'S', 2]]
>>> search_and_increment(lis,"E,F")
>>> lis
[['A', 'B', 4], ['C', 'D', 4], ['E', 'F', 6], ['A', 'S', 2]]
```

Comment: Seeing as the OP is a student, it might be better to promote some good practices in the answer. (Like not using a global variable, or giving `func` a descriptive name.)

Comment: The *elements* of the lists are *tuples*, your code and solution uses *lists* which of course makes this much easier since list are mutable unlike tuples. OP specified tuples in his problem.

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing is a bit tricky, because tuples are immutable, which means they cannot be changed. Instead you have to copy and readd them.

If you really need to use tuples, this code should work (even though it’s probably totally not the nicest solution). However, this solution does not keep the list elements in order.

Otherwise, jamylak’s solutions look way better.

```
def search_and_inc_list(tuple_list, search_tuple):
    found = False

    for index, element in enumerate(tuple_list):
        last_index = len(search_tuple)
        if element[0:last_index] == search_tuple:
            new_element = element[0:last_index] + (element[last_index]+1,)
            found = True

            tuple_list[index] = new_element

            # You may add break here if elements are unique

    if found == False:
        new_tuple = search_tuple + (1,)
        tuple_list.append(new_tuple)


mylist = [("A","B",3),("C","D",4),("E","F",5)]
print(mylist)
search_and_inc_list(mylist, ("A", "B"))
print(mylist)
search_and_inc_list(mylist, ("A", "C"))

# [('A', 'B', 3), ('C', 'D', 4), ('E', 'F', 5)]
# [('A', 'B', 4), ('C', 'D', 4), ('E', 'F', 5)]
# [('A', 'B', 4), ('C', 'D', 4), ('E', 'F', 5), ('A', 'C', 1)]
```